# Merging extracted files Into a working program

Tags: windows, rar, winrar

I downloaded 33 files (`.rar`) using uTorrent and extracted all of them using WinRAR. All are in one folder, appropriately named.

However, I have no idea how to merge them all into the one working program like they are supposed to be.

Comment: Just post a link from the screenshot, without that, we can't really guess what your problem is. Alternatively, make a list of the folder as you see it now and include it in your question please.

Answer (score 1):

**If** archives had pattern `file.partNN.rar` you had just unpack *.part01.rar - all other will be done automatically (and splitted files joined)

Answer (score 0):

Just choose any one of those files and use extract the contents. Use `extract here...` option if this is convenient for you. If all files are stored withing the same directory and undamaged, archiving software will recreate the initial executable automatically.